# Detect if childelement immediately comes after starting of parent div or not

Tags: jquery

I m running into little trouble. I have following HTML code

```
<div id="parentdiv">
        This is test immediately in a parent div, not within child element
        many more text comes. 
        <p class="childelement">This is under child element</p>
        Another bunch of text also comes here
    </div>
```

The `p tag` with class `childelement` may occur one or more time anywhere within `parentdiv`. All I want to do is detect one of the either two situations below:-

1. Detect if `childelement` immediately comes after starting of parent
   div or not.
2. Detect if there is any text before the `childelement`

What i basically want to do is, if `childelement` satisfies point 2, then I will append margin-top style to this element, otherwise not.

What I tried is

```
$('.childelement:gt(0)').css({'margin-top':'5pt'});
```

This works well for all `childelement` in a parent div,if there is `childelement` right after starting tag of parent div. But if I remove this first occurrence of `childelement`, the `margin-top` css is lost in second `childelement` because after removing first element, its `index becomes 0` .

Just a hint would be well enough for me.

Any help will highly be appreciable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` method and read the `previousSibling` property the of the element, note that I have used `$.trim()` to exclude textNodes that don't have visible characters, if you want to include those nodes, you can remove the method.

```
$('#parentdiv .childelement:first-child').filter(function() {
    return this.previousSibling 
           && $.trim(this.previousSibling.nodeValue).length;  
}).css({'margin-top':'5pt'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tcb4s/

---

An update made by [@LoVeSmItH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744987/lovesmith):

```
$('#parentdiv .childelement:first-child').filter(function() {
     var sit=this.previousSibling && $.trim(this.previousSibling.nodeValue).length;
     if ($.trim(sit)!="") {
         return sit;
     } else {
        $('.childelement:gt(0)').css({'margin-top':'5pt'});
     }
}).css({'margin-top':'5pt'});
```

---

My suggestion based on the edit:

```
var $child = $('#parentdiv .childelement'),
    $first = $child.filter(':first-child').filter(function() {
               return this.previousSibling 
                      && $.trim(this.previousSibling.nodeValue).length;  
             });

if ($first.length) $first.css({'margin-top':'5pt'});
else $child.not(':first').css({'margin-top':'5pt'});
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Had little issue when no `childelement` were removed, the second `childelement` would lost a `margin-top` css. I have fixed this I will update your answer. Thanks a ton! you saved my day